# New activity (screen) and "Application has stopped..."

Tags: android, screen, new-operator

in my app I am trying to add new screen. In my activity I've:

```
public void addItem(View v) {
       Intent i = new Intent(SQLiteListActivity.this, add_screen.class);
       startActivity(i);
}
```

In add_screen.java:

```
public class add_screen extends Activity {
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       TextView tv = new TextView(this);
       tv.setText("Hello, Android");
       setContentView(tv);
   }
}
```

In file add_screen.xml I've layout this screen. In file AndroidManifest.xml I added this next activity, especially:

```
    <activity class=".Add_screen" android:name="ADD_ITEM" android:label="Add item">
  </activity>
```

I am still getting an error message about "Application has been stopped." I am newbie in Android development, I tried to do this by some tutorial, I've everything by it, but I don't know why, I'm still getting the error message above...

Can you help me, please, with this problem? I've no idea, what could be wrong.

Comment: At first sight i would rename .Add_screen to .add_screen because of the case.
Did you try the DDMS Perspective of Eclipse - if you are using Eclipse. It provides in depth explanation of errors and memory usage.

Comment: I'm sorry, of course .add_screen is lowercase letter... Here is my statement of LogCat - http://pastebin.com/racczMQQ. But from this statement I'm not very wise

Comment: Your error is: `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.codegod.android/com.codegod.android.add_screen}`.  Can you post the whole of your `AndroidManifest.xml` pelase?

Comment: Hi dave.c, thank you for your reply. The whole [code]AndroidManifest.xml[/code] is here: http://pastebin.com/ge3hdHLL
Thanks for any help! I don't know still how to fix this error... :/

Comment: is `add_screen` in the same package as `SQLiteListActivity`? i.e. in `com.codegod.android`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the activity tag in your manifest with this instead:

```
<activity
    android:name=".add_screen"
    android:label="Add item"
    >
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You shouldn't need the class attribute, I don't even know if that's recognized.

Edit: Try the above instead?

Comment: Hmm, updated my answer. Try adding a default category to the activity as shown.